# Built in admin ajax hooks?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax, hooks

I'm developing a plugin and using regular hooks and filters.
However, I'm now trying to bind my function to responses from WP's admin ajax calls.

For example, in the [Plugins Add New screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins_Add_New_Screen) I would like to run my function after ajax installation of a plugin is complete successfully and the "Activate" button appears.
How can I trigger my function on successfull ajax response there?

Using "**plugin_install_action_links**" I can control the action links through php, but what is the ajax equivelent (if there is one)?

Comment: Is this the activation of your plugin or the activation of other plugins?

Comment: It's actually not activation, but rather installation of other plugins. but it can also be binding to ajax activation of other plugins, this will also help.

Comment: and you've asked how to do the generic non-WP case of intercepting an AJAX request made by jQuery in javascript?

Comment: Not non-WP case. I'm looking for a WP hook for ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress core is something where you cannot create your own hooks.
Hooks in WordPress are created with these

```
apply_filters
apply_filters_ref_array
apply_filters_deprecated
do_action
do_action_ref_array
do_action_deprecated
```

The only thing you can do is to register your function to certain WordPress core hook. But where are these hooks?

You may expect these hooks in a function called `activate_plugin`.

```
File: wp-admin/includes/plugin.php
512: /**
513:  * Attempts activation of plugin in a "sandbox" and redirects on success.
514:  *
515:  * A plugin that is already activated will not attempt to be activated again.
516:  *
517:  * The way it works is by setting the redirection to the error before trying to
518:  * include the plugin file. If the plugin fails, then the redirection will not
519:  * be overwritten with the success message. Also, the options will not be
520:  * updated and the activation hook will not be called on plugin error.
521:  *
522:  * It should be noted that in no way the below code will actually prevent errors
523:  * within the file. The code should not be used elsewhere to replicate the
524:  * "sandbox", which uses redirection to work.
525:  * {@source 13 1}
526:  *
527:  * If any errors are found or text is outputted, then it will be captured to
528:  * ensure that the success redirection will update the error redirection.
529:  *
530:  * @since 2.5.0
531:  *
532:  * @param string $plugin       Plugin path to main plugin file with plugin data.
533:  * @param string $redirect     Optional. URL to redirect to.
534:  * @param bool   $network_wide Optional. Whether to enable the plugin for all sites in the network
535:  *                             or just the current site. Multisite only. Default false.
536:  * @param bool   $silent       Optional. Whether to prevent calling activation hooks. Default false.
537:  * @return WP_Error|null WP_Error on invalid file or null on success.
538:  */
539: function activate_plugin( $plugin, $redirect = '', $network_wide = false, $silent = false ) {
```

> Note there is a parameter `@param bool   $silent` that is optional that will **prevent** calling activation hooks. By default it is set to `false`.

In that function at the moment, you can find hooks:

```
File: wp-admin/includes/plugin.php
563:        if ( ! $silent ) {
564:            /**
565:             * Fires before a plugin is activated.
566:             *
567:             * If a plugin is silently activated (such as during an update),
568:             * this hook does not fire.
569:             *
570:             * @since 2.9.0
571:             *
572:             * @param string $plugin       Plugin path to main plugin file with plugin data.
573:             * @param bool   $network_wide Whether to enable the plugin for all sites in the network
574:             *                             or just the current site. Multisite only. Default is false.
575:             */
576:            do_action( 'activate_plugin', $plugin, $network_wide );
```

One more...

```
File: wp-admin/includes/plugin.php
563:        if ( ! $silent ) {
...
578:            /**
579:             * Fires as a specific plugin is being activated.
580:             *
581:             * This hook is the "activation" hook used internally by register_activation_hook().
582:             * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$plugin`, refers to the plugin basename.
583:             *
584:             * If a plugin is silently activated (such as during an update), this hook does not fire.
585:             *
586:             * @since 2.0.0
587:             *
588:             * @param bool $network_wide Whether to enable the plugin for all sites in the network
589:             *                           or just the current site. Multisite only. Default is false.
590:             */
591:            do_action( "activate_{$plugin}", $network_wide );
```

And one you actually need...

```
File: wp-admin/includes/plugin.php
605:        if ( ! $silent ) {
606:            /**
607:             * Fires after a plugin has been activated.
608:             *
609:             * If a plugin is silently activated (such as during an update),
610:             * this hook does not fire.
611:             *
612:             * @since 2.9.0
613:             *
614:             * @param string $plugin       Plugin path to main plugin file with plugin data.
615:             * @param bool   $network_wide Whether to enable the plugin for all sites in the network
616:             *                             or just the current site. Multisite only. Default is false.
617:             */
618:            do_action( 'activated_plugin', $plugin, $network_wide );
```

I just searched for the hook generator functions such as `do_action`.

---

What you do `plugin_install_action_links` is a **filer** type of hook. Filter are typically there to `replace` certain things.

```
File: wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugin-install-list-table.php
519:            /**
520:             * Filters the install action links for a plugin.
521:             *
522:             * @since 2.7.0
523:             *
524:             * @param array $action_links An array of plugin action hyperlinks. Defaults are links to Details and Install Now.
525:             * @param array $plugin       The plugin currently being listed.
526:             */
527:            $action_links = apply_filters( 'plugin_install_action_links', $action_links, $plugin );
```

> Using "plugin_install_action_links" I can control the action links through php, but what is the ajax equivelent (if there is one)?

There is a file called `admin-ajax.php`. You can examine this file, and you can use hooks to do your specific things, but there are no filters defined at the moment in `admin-ajax.php`.

Comment: Thanks.
When searching for a way to connect an action to plugin install (not activate), I saw two action hooks in plugin-install.php. one is "install_plugins_{$tab}" and the other is "install_plugins_pre_{$tab}".
Could you tell me what exactly is "tab" referring to in this case? How can I associate my function to the ajax installation in this case?

Comment: I will try to answer you in here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250326/composite-hooks-question