# What is $tab in `install_plugins_{$tab}` hook?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, installation, tabs

Goodman asked:

> When searching for a way to connect an action to plugin install (not activate), I saw two action hooks in `plugin-install.php`. one is `install_plugins_{$tab}` and the other is `install_plugins_pre_{$tab}`.
>
> Could you tell me what exactly is `$tab` referring to in this case? How can I associate my function to the ajax installation in this case?

Comment: Whose question is that? Yours?

Comment: It was from the comments but deserves some detailed explanation. Will add the reference later.

Comment: Then please edit the question. It doesn't matter who asked it first. Also please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem, do not include the word "question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the plugin-install.php inside the WordPress dashboard, there may be many tabs:

```
wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=featured
wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=popular
wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=recommended
...
```

[image: plugin-install.php tabs]

Here is the function you referenced:

```
File: wp-admin/plugin-install.php
145: /**
146:  * Fires after the plugins list table in each tab of the Install Plugins screen.
147:  *
148:  * The dynamic portion of the action hook, `$tab`, allows for targeting
149:  * individual tabs, for instance 'install_plugins_plugin-information'.
150:  *
151:  * @since 2.7.0
152:  *
153:  * @param int $paged The current page number of the plugins list table.
154:  */
155: do_action( "install_plugins_{$tab}", $paged ); ?>
156: 
157:    <span class="spinner"></span>
158: </div>
```

And `$tab` is actually what you get via `$_GET['tab']`:

```
File: wp-admin/plugin-install.php
08: // TODO route this pages via a specific iframe handler instead of the do_action below
09: if ( !defined( 'IFRAME_REQUEST' ) && isset( $_GET['tab'] ) && ( 'plugin-information' == $_GET['tab'] ) )
10:     define( 'IFRAME_REQUEST', true );
11:
```

in our case the tabs would be:

```
featured, popular, recommended
```

based on the URL.

#### Related blitz quest:

> Thank you. what about "tab=search"? my current problem is that when i start typing in the search box, once the plugin list appears, the various actions do not seem to apply.

This seems like a completely new action (read: new question). Have you tried the

```
action:query-themes
```

aka function:

```
wp_ajax_query_themes
```

If you need more help, you may create a new quest with details and someone may try to dig deeper.

Comment: Thank you. what about "tab=search"? 
my current problem is that when i start typing in the search box, once the plugin list appears, the various actions do not seem to apply.

Comment: @EranG, I tried to reply short, looks again like a new subject to research and discover, even though we have `tab=search` we have Ajax requests down below.